# WebLogicServer doesn't create DemoIdentity.jks

Tags: java, weblogic

Whenever I install WebLogicServer, it doesn't create DemoIdentity.jks under base_domain. As such, I can't use SSL 7002.

I can't create a a new .jks file using instructions here : [create new jks](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/05/28/how-to-create-a-new-demoidentity-jks/)

It gives me error: java.security.invalidkeyexception : exponent is larget than modulus
Make sure the CA files are in DER format.

Which they are.

Is there a reason for this happening? Any solutions to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to bypass this issue,  use the "-noskid" parameter when running utils.CertGen .

Comment: Thanks! That worked!! Had a hard time searching for the answer in the net.